# make an app that displays desktop on iphone in vr on unity

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, ios12

I would like to make an AR iPhone app in unity that places an object in the real world which you can then interact with it on your iPhone. like you have a bar at the bottom of your screen and you can drag the objects into the ar world and interact with them with the ability of hand tracking. This will work kind of like the meta 2 interface https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7ZDaiDwnxY which you can grab things and drag them. it uses hand tracking to do this.

I have done some research on this but, I need some help doing this because I don't know where to start and how to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

To get started in mobile AR in Unity, I would recommend starting with Unity's resources:

https://unity.com/solutions/mobile-ar

Here's a tutorial resource for learning ARKit:

https://unity3d.com/learn/learn-arkit

As for hand tracking, obviously the Meta 2 has specialized hardware to execute its features... you shouldn't necessarily be expecting to achieve the same feature set with only a phone driving your experience. Leap Motion is the most common hand tracker I've seen integrated into VR and AR setups and it works well, but if you really need hand tracking with just a phone, you could check out ManoMotion which seeks to bring hand tracking and gesture recognition to ARKit, although I haven't personally worked with it.